# Retrieve data in a single row using group keyword in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I have a table tbl_marks with columns and data as below.

```
name    id  section1 section2 section3 section4      year
cherry   1      100      101      102      103       2016
cherry   1      200      201      202      203       2015
cherry   1      300      301      302      303       2014
```

Expected Output Format :

```
cherry 1 100101102103 200201202203 300301302303
```

I would like to have scores of all sections of one year to be concatenated and then followed by scores of another year separated by space.
So I need 5 columns in single row. (name, id, scores of year1, scores of year2, scores of year3)

Please let me know how should i update the query below. Thank you.

Query : select  name, id, ??? from tbl_marks group by id;

Comment: I have tried to edit the data rows for readability, but you seem to retract those edits. The way the data is formated now makes it almost impossible to understand how the data is grouped

Comment: can you clarify if you want `100101102103`, `200201202203` and `300301302303` in separate columns in the output, or just `100101102103 200201202203 300301302303` in one column?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```
SELECT name,
       id,
       GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(section1, section2, section3, section4)
                    ORDER BY section1 SEPARATOR ' ')
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY name, id
```

This answer assumes that you want three columns in your result set, the three columns being the `name`, `id`, and a CSV list of marks for that name/id group (`123,456,789` in this case).

## SQLFiddle

 (courtesy of @Luke)

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT` merges the grouped values in a single text field, it may solve the unique issue at hand but is, when used for pivoting, at best a fragile solution depending on arbitrary delimiters, which may easily break during future development. In practice `GROUP_CONCAT` should only be used for display purposes.

Comment: Looks like I missed few details.I updated my question. Please let me know the workarounf for this. Thanks.

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot Time and Luke. Need a little edit - Removed one ) as there are two  )) after SEPARATOR ' '.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I want to have 5 columns instead of 3 columns as per my updated question. I get to run your query today and found that it only returns 3 columns. Please let me know how can I separate them into 5 columns. Thanks.

Comment: I get that GROUP_CONCAT returns a string. Need to figure out how can we divide the result into separate columns.

Answer (score 0):

The process you are looking for is called 'pivoting' and is not *dynamically* possible in basic SQL as it is a set-based language.

Just retrieve the rows in your business logic code and turn it into columns there.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to use is `group_concat()` and `concat()` functions of MySQL, e.g.

```
select name, group_concat(concat(value1, value2)) 
from table
group by name
```

Here is the sample **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5871d/1/0)**.

Comment: concats the values within a column only, the questions asks to concat values within a row, across columns first then concat the result of this.

Comment: Updated the answer and corresponding fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is self joins.

```
SELECT a.id,a.name,CONCAT(a.section1, a.section2, a.section3, a.section4) as val2015
,CONCAT(b.section1, b.section2, b.section3, b.section4) as val2016
,CONCAT(c.section1, c.section2, c.section3, c.section4) as val2017
FROM test a
LEFT JOIN test b
ON b.id=a.id
LEFT JOIN test c
ON c.id=a.id
WHERE a.year=2015 AND b.year=2016 AND c.year=2017
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e5985d/3)

Edit: Changed the query according to comments.

Comment: Looks like I missed few details. I updated my question. Please let me know the workaround for this. Thanks.

Comment: Any way to have dynamic and not limited to 3 specific years? What happens when I add a data row for 2018?

Comment: Unfortunatly this method is limited to either hard code each year, or to dynamicly create the questions in a scripting language like php. On the other hand each year gets its own column, where t group_concat method puts all years separated by space in the same column. So which method you use depends on the output you want and how you can handle it in the next step.